# Change 3 background Images based on current time in 3 locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

I have 3 images on a page, each needs to change to reflect the time (day or night) in that location.

I have got it so if it is between 7pm & 7am in each timezone the images change to night, but I want it so if in UK after 7pm the UK image is night but the New York & LA image is still day, as it would be in that location...

This is my current code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function() {
        var hour = new Date().getHours();
        if (hour > 7 && hour <= 19) {
            // morning
            $('.contact').addClass('day');
        } else {
            // night
            $('.contact').addClass('night');
        }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Is this possible just using jQuery?

HTML

```
<section>
        <article class="col-1-3 contact one">
            <h2>London</h2>
            <div class="col-1-2 address one">
                <address>
                3rd Floor<br/>
                9 Chapel Place<br/>
                London, EC2A 3DQ<br/>
                <a href="tel:+442078707414">+44 207 870 7414</a><br/>
                <a class="dir" href="" target="_blank">Get directions ></a>
                </address>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-1-3 contact three">
            <h2>New York</h2>
            <div class="col-1-2 address three">
                <address>
                46F, 10<br/>
                East 29th St<br/>
                New York, 10016<br/>
                <a href="tel:+16317769772">tel:+1 631 776 9772</a><br/>
                <a class="dir" href="" target="_blank">Get directions ></a>
                </address>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-1-3 contact two">
            <h2>Los Angeles</h2>
                <div class="col-1-2 address two">
                <address>
                4624 Cahuenga Blvd<br/>
                Unit 302<br/>
                Los Angeles, CA 91602<br/>
                <a href="tel:+12094109977">tel:+1 209 410 9977</a><br/>
                <a class="dir" href="" target="_blank">Get directions ></a>
                </address>
                </div>
        </article>
        <article class="col-1-1 copy" id="post-<?php echo $page->ID; ?>">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this is to use a UTC time, then add or subtract the offset for the locations you want to display.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But this being locally executed, it should return the local time anyway, shouldn't it? Why wouldn't this code work as is? I don't see any problem with it as it is now. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It works as in it changes all 3 images (London, NY and LA) to night after 7pm in UK for example. But, it is not night in NY & La after 7pm in UK so I want UK to be night and NY & LA to still be day...

Comment: @JeremyThille yes, but it only works for one time. The OP wants it to work for three.

Comment: Aaah, I get it now. We need to have all three times on the same page.

Comment: Yes..I have added HTML to help clarify.

Comment: Thanks for including your HTML. I added an answer for you showing the logic I mentioned in my first comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can get the current UTC time and then add or subtract the timezone offset for each location from that central date. You can then loop over the `.contact` elements using a `data` attribute to specify the offset of each location and updating the class of the element based on that. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setClasses() {
    var now = new Date();
    
    $('.contact').each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      var local = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours() + $el.data('utcoffset'), now.getUTCMinutes());
      var hour = local.getHours();
      var isMorning = hour > 7 && hour <= 19;
      $el.toggleClass('day', isMorning);
      $el.toggleClass('night', !isMorning);
    });
  }

  setInterval(setClasses, 1000);
  setClasses();
});
```

```css
.day {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  color: #fdfdb7;
}

.night {
  background-color: #00008b;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <article class="col-1-3 contact one" data-utcoffset="0">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <div class="col-1-2 address one">
      <address>
        3rd Floor<br/>
        9 Chapel Place<br/>
        London, EC2A 3DQ<br/>
        <a href="tel:+442078707414">+44 207 870 7414</a><br/>
        <a class="dir" href="" target="_blank">Get directions ></a>
      </address>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="col-1-3 contact three" data-utcoffset="-5">
    <h2>New York</h2>
    <div class="col-1-2 address three">
      <address>
        46F, 10<br/>
        East 29th St<br/>
        New York, 10016<br/>
        <a href="tel:+16317769772">tel:+1 631 776 9772</a><br/>
        <a class="dir" href="" target="_blank">Get directions ></a>
      </address>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="col-1-3 contact two" data-utcoffset="-8">
    <h2>Los Angeles</h2>
    <div class="col-1-2 address two">
      <address>
        4624 Cahuenga Blvd<br/>
        Unit 302<br/>
        Los Angeles, CA 91602<br/>
        <a href="tel:+12094109977">tel:+1 209 410 9977</a><br/>
        <a class="dir" href="" target="_blank">Get directions ></a>
      </address>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Also note that running this every second in your page is a little wasteful given how unlikely the classes are to change. I'd suggest changing the interval to once a minute at most.

Comment: That's the one!... Seems to work , I am in UK and it is day pic, NY and LA are night. Thanks Rory & everyone that helped.

Comment: You can test it yourself by changing your system time.

Comment: You're right. It's because dates are given by reference, not value, so simply creating a new variable to amend the date won't work. I updated my answer so that the UTC date is calculated within each iteration of the loop. It also helps to tidy the logic a little too :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add an offset data value to your html in the `.contact`-elements. For example London is GMT+0, give it `data-offset="0"` New York is GMT-5 give it `data-offset="-5"`.

The use your jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function() {
    $('.contact').each(function() {
        var date = new Data();
        var hour = (date.getHours() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) + parseInt($(this).data('offset'));
        if (hour > 7 && hour <= 19) {
            // morning
            $('this').addClass('day');
        } else {
            // night
            $('this').addClass('night');
        }
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

I did not run that code, though, better double check it before using.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if a user is in a different timezone than UK? Example, user is in Australia (could be UTC + 10).

Comment: @agarwalankur85 Good point. `New Date().getHours()` needs the `getTimezoneOffset` to be set to GMT0 to prevent that. I'll edit